# Is this an odd function?

Tags: integration

I have this function:

> \begin{equation*}
>   f(x)=% 
>   \begin{cases}
>     1  &x\in\left[ -\pi,-\pi/2\right[ \\
>     -1 &x\in\left[ -\pi/2,0\right[\\
>     1 & x\in\left[ 0,\pi/2\right[ \\
>     -1 & x\in\left[ \pi/2,\pi\right]\\
>   \end{cases}
> \end{equation*}

First I thought that it was odd, but then I realized that $f(0) = 1 \neq - f(0) = -1$ was true. Does it matter when you calculate an integral and want to use the property of an odd function? For instance can I still deduce that:

> \begin{equation*}
>   \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx = 0
> \end{equation*}

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of the function in a finite number of points (so that you get an odd function) does not affect the integral, so yes, the integral is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Redefining $f$ at $0$ (to be $0$) and $\frac\pi2$ (to be $1$) would make $f$ odd. Since only two points were changed (or any finite number of points), the integral is unaffected, so you can still deduce that
$$
\int_{-a}^af(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0
$$